# How to view GitLab cummulative commit history by user

Tags: gitlab

We just migrated from SVN to GitLab and I would like to view all of my commit history across all the projects I worked on. Spanning over a decade. I can see the commit history for Individual projects but not "All" of the projects I worked on in the Organization. Want to view the cumulative commit history.

Does **GitLab** Enterprise Edition offer such visibility to a user with a Maintainer role? If it does can anyone point me how. I skimmed through the docs and couple of posts but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to view to your commit history for all projects is by using the Gitlab API

Specifcally the projects API in order to retrieve all projects you are member of https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

```
GET /projects
```

Retrieve the `project id` and pass it to the commits API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/commits
```

Finally we can combine them to the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
AUTHOR=$1
ACCESS_TOKEN=$2

curl -s  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?membership=true" | jq '.[] | "\(.id) \(.name)"' | while read line
do
        line=$(echo $line | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/')
        PROJECT_ID=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1)
        PROJECT_NAME=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2-)

        curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/repository/commits?per_page=1000000" | jq  --arg v "$AUTHOR" '.[]  | select(.author_name==$v) |"|| DATE=\(.authored_date) || SHA=\(.id) || MESSAGE=\(.message) || CHANGES_URL=\(.web_url)"' | while read commit
                do
                        echo PROJECT=$PROJECT_NAME ${commit:1:-1}
                        echo \n
                done
done
```

Execute the script:

```
./script "AUTHOR_NAME" "ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

The output would contain all the commits for the projects that the **AUTHOR_NAME** is member of, with the following format

```
PROJECT=<PROJECT_NAME> || DATE=<DATE_COMMITED> || SHA=<COMMIT_SHA> || MESSAGE=<COMMIT_MESSAGE> || CHANGES_URL=URL_TO_VIEW_THE_COMMIT_CHANGES
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the project IDs and extracting the [repository contributors via the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#contributors) should help provide that data, albeit it only via a custom script.

There indeed doesn't seem to be a polished feature for it, just the mixed `Activity` in your profile.